# axios post request getting 404

Tags: node.js, api, post, axios

tried all the solution online but it doesn't suit mine.

I have tried to put console.log between lines in my post request,

but it shows nothing,

also got no response object ,

so I guess it must be something blocking me sending request ,

got axios cors installed,

got register button inside the form tag,

got method="post" on the form,

also tried not using absolute path,

please help me out here
been stuck here for days

below from RegisterPage

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useRef } from "react";
import makeToast from "../Toaster";

const RegisterPage = (props) => {
  const usernameRef = useRef();
  const passwordRef = useRef();
  const emailRef = useRef();

  const handleRegister = (e) => {
    e.preventdefault();
    const username = usernameRef.current.value;
    const password = passwordRef.current.value;
    const email = emailRef.current.value;

    axios
      .post(
        "/register",
        {
          username,
          password,
          email,
        },
        { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" } }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        makeToast("success", response.data.message);
        props.history.push("/login");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.name);
        console.log(err.message);
        makeToast("error", err.message);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="inputSession">
      <div className="inputContainer">
        <div className="inputDetail">
          <form method="post">
            <div className="inputDetail">
              <label htmlFor="username">username</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="username"
                id="username"
                placeholder="please input your username"
                ref={usernameRef}
              ></input>
            </div>
            <div className="inputDetail">
              <label htmlFor="password">password</label>
              <input
                type="password"
                name="password"
                id="password"
                placeholder="please input your password"
                ref={passwordRef}
                autoComplete="off"
              ></input>
            </div>
            <div className="inputDetail">
              <label htmlFor="email">email</label>
              <input
                type="email"
                name="email"
                id="email"
                placeholder="please input your email"
                ref={emailRef}
              ></input>
            </div>
            <button onClick={handleRegister}>register</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RegisterPage;
```

below from app.js

```
import BloggerPage from "./Pages/BloggerPage";
import ChatroomPage from "./Pages/ChatroomPage";
import DashboardPage from "./Pages/DashboardPage";
import LoginPage from "./Pages/LoginPage";
import PhotoPage from "./Pages/PhotoPage";
import RegisterPage from "./Pages/RegisterPage";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/register" element={<RegisterPage />}></Route>
        <Route exact path="/login" element={<LoginPage />}></Route>
        <Route exact path="/photo" element={<PhotoPage />}></Route>
        <Route exact path="/blogger" element={<BloggerPage />}></Route>
        <Route exact path="/dashboard" element={<DashboardPage />}></Route>
        <Route exact path="/chatroom" element={<ChatroomPage />}></Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[another pic related to the detailed of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6XK9.png)

Comment: missing the header for form data? axios
      .post(url, formData, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
    });

Comment: really????? is that a must ? I thought that is option??let me try out

Comment: What's running on `localhost:3000`? and the route/handler for `/register`

Comment: my entire frontend react is running on localhost 3000 backend running on 3001 sorry, I do not get the idea of second question @Matt

Comment: still not working ;-; Request failed with status code 404 @SantoshKaranam

Comment: your request is made to "localhost:3000/localhost:3000/register"

Comment: do I need to add async and await on this ??

Comment: You spelled wrong `e.preventDefault()` and should change url to `/register` only

Comment: thank you :(
already correct my spelling re-render my code up there :( please take another look 
since I have changed /register already
btw is that any document I can refer to  "localhost:3000/localhost:3000/register"

@Johan

Comment: but I used .then() already
should I change to async and await ?
ain't they the same function
feel like they do the same thing here
but I am not quite sure as well 
@DrashtiKheni

Comment: create a codesandbox with a reproducable code so we can help

Comment: sorry, has not tried before
is this the one u referring about 
https://codesandbox.io/

or I have to add it into my post
@Johan

Comment: Yes this is this codesandbox. You can login, create your code et then share the link in your post

Comment: @Johan rightawayyyyy

Comment: https://github.com/ksyu1113/Authentication-chatApp

sorry wasn't quite familiar with GitHub
@Johan

is that also ok

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/ksyu1113/Authentication-chatApp/master?workspaceId=8d8f81e3-f6f4-42cb-ac40-1b1d0801a45d     @Johan